# error installing mercurial plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, mercurialeclipse

I am trying to install the picasa web android sample in Eclipse so I am
[following all the steps](http://samples.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/picasa-android-sample/instructions.html?r=default), until I get to the step where I have to install
the Mercurial plugin for Eclipse.

So in eclipse I try to add the plugin from http://cbes.javaforge.com/update
as stated on the hg site but then I get the following error and eclipse cannot
complete the install because of the following dependency:

> Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
>
> com.intland.hgbinary.win32.feature.group [1.9.3.v201110131844] cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Are you trying to install it in Linux? If so you need to deselect the Windows mercurial binaries from the install screen.